# How do I scrape multiple images from a website and save them on a specific folder using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I would like to scrape images from a search result of a website. However, if there are no search results it would print an indication then close the browser. For example, I would like to search for xcom at https://gog-games.com/. It has three results, save those results on a folder and print an indication that it was successful, and close the browser. How would I go on about this? Here is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

search = input("What game are you looking for? ")
#if there is a result:
PATH = r"C:\Coding\Codes\Python\msedgedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge(PATH)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://gog-games.com/")
searchbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/div/form/input")
searchbox.send_keys(search)
searchbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#save each image at "C:\Coding\Codes\Python\Image_Dataset\image_name"
#close the browser
#print("Results saved")

#elif there is no result:
    #close the browser
    #print("There is no result")
```

Comment: maybe it would be simpler to get all `src` from HTML and use module `requests` or `urllib.request` to download them.

Answer (score 2):

You can get `src` from all `<img>` in HTML and use module `requests` or `urllib.request` to download them.

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests

# --- constants ---

PATH = r"C:\Coding\Codes\Python\msedgedriver.exe"
FOLDER = r"C:\Coding\Codes\Python\Image_Dataset\image_name"
#FOLDER = 'test'

os.makedirs(FOLDER, exist_ok=True)

# ---

#search = input("What game are you looking for? ")
search = "Punk Wars"

driver = webdriver.Edge(PATH)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://gog-games.com/")

searchbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@id="search-bar"]/input')
searchbox.send_keys(search)
searchbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(3)

all_iamges = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="container search"]//img[@src]')

for img in all_iamges:
    url = img.get_attribute('src')
    filename = url.split("/")[-1]
    print('url:', url)
    print('filename:', filename)
    print('-----')
    
    full_path = os.path.join(FOLDER, filename)
    
    response = requests.get(url)
    with open(full_path, "wb") as fh:
        fh.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much for this! I added driver.quit() at the end so it would close the browser after it saved all the images. Btw, where can I learn about finding the XPath of a certain container?

Comment: In `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome you can select element and it can give XPATH but rather like your `"/html/body/header/div/form/input"`. Some browsers may need exension to select XPATH. I use `DevTools` to select item, see its HTML and manually create `XPATH` or `CSS SELECTOR`. Selenium can also find  `by_name`, `by_id`, `by_class`, etc. so sometimes it doesn't need full `XPATH`. In Firefox in `DevTools` you can also use `JavaScript Console` to test `XPATH` with code `$x("xpath")` - so I can see if it selects expected elements. Chrome should have similar function somewhere in `DevTools`.

Comment: what mean of this line ```PATH = r"C:\Coding\Codes\Python\msedgedriver.exe"```?

Comment: @frankfurt it is path to driver for web browser Microsoft Edge and this path is used in `webdriver.Edge(PATH)`. You can see it in question - so I keep it.  But I tested code with `Firefox`/`Chrome` and I have drivers for these browsers in special folder and I don't have to use manually PATH in code.